# How can I play videos in a framebuffer?

Tags: video, command-line, vlc

If I don't want to install a GUI, just install a minimal Ubuntu amd64.

Ok, but: I heard that I can still run e.g.: Firefox in a "framebuffer" (?), so I'm asking, that how can I run e.g.: a VLC media player through a framebuffer under console, without "GUI"?

Comment: you can't run a gui element without a gui, how would you even play a video if you don't have a gui to draw a window for it. and i'm pretty sure that what you're referring to is this <---http://www.calsoftlabs.com/whitepapers/firefox_gtk_dfb.html

Comment: mplayer supports it.  I can;t say I know anything about it, but a quick Google on "mplayer Linux framebuffer" came up with quite a bit, though most of what I saw were how-to's for other distros; Gentoo, Arch, etc. From what I gather you MAY have to do a specific compile of mplayer, or maybe not.  But yes, you can do video from framebuffer.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226995/how-to-watch-films-images-without-x

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Make sure your console starts in framebuffer mode.
- Add your user to 'video' group:
- Install mplayer `sudo apt-get install mplayer`
- Run `mplayer -vo fbdev video.avi` 
  If that fails, try `-vo fbdev2`

---

I was able to run a videofile in framebuffer with a default installation if Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: tested under Fedora14: it works. wow. :D lol. but how can i set it to run in full screen?

Comment: There is a scale argument '-vf scale=800x600' ... put your resolution.

Comment: mplayer -fs may start it in fullscreen

Comment: To use a specific framebuffer device: `mplayer -vo fbdev:/dev/fb1 video.avi`

Comment: How to achieve "Make sure your console starts in framebuffer mode"? Edit: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32620019/c-linux-how-to-takeover-the-framebuffer

Comment: On my TTY I need to use mplayer -vo fbdev2 video.avi to play it.

Answer (score 5):

I use VLC (ncurses edition) via `sudo apt-get install vlc-nox`.

I also installed Alsa utilities, to control the volume `sudo apt-get install alsa-utils`.

You'll be downloading a lot of multimedia libraries, without the X windows stuff.

Make sure your userID is a member of `video` and `audio` groups.

You can kick off a DVD via `vlc dvd:///dev/dvd`.

Or as a local file `vlc "~Videos/Fraggle Rock - Live By The Rule of the Rock.avi"`.

HDMI audio at the framebuffer level has been problematic for me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

VLC should be able to play on framebuffer. using --vo fb but i couldn't make it work.

Another alternative that works well is mpv. setting the --vo option.

```
mpv --vo drm myvideo.mp4
```

you can check which ones you have with `mpv --vo` help.

for example

```
Available video outputs:
  libmpv           render API for libmpv
  gpu              Shader-based GPU Renderer
  sdl              SDL 2.0 Renderer
  null             Null video output
  image            Write video frames to image files
  tct              true-color terminals
  caca             libcaca
  drm              Direct Rendering Manager (software scaling)
```

caca will run on a framebuffer terminal using ascii characters.

tct will run on a fb terminal using ascii as well.
if the terminal is running inside x11 i noticed it does look better using tct and doesnt use ascii.

and drm will use the framebuffer in direct rendering. which has a lot more colors and actual pixels.